# Laravel Property does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I need to transfer data from Mysq table (Paniers) to another Mysql table (Commandes) and delete the data from first table after transfer.

Here is my code:

```
function Commande(Request $request) { 
        $pn = $request->input('id'); 
        $pdr = Panier::find($pn);
        $user = Commande::create([
        'ID_User'    => $pdr->ID_User,
        'ID_Piece'   => $pdr->ID_Piece,
        'QTE'        => $pdr->QTE,
        ]);
        if($user){
            if($pdr->delete())
            {
                echo 'Commande Confirmée';
            }        
        }
    }
```

I get this error:

```
"Property [ID_User] does not exist on this collection instance."
```

If i do this it works but instead of getting all data i only get the first line. I need to get all lines of data!

```
$pdr = Panier::find($pn)->first();
```

Comment: `Mysq table to another Mysql table`  is the target table empty?  You could just `rename` the table in that case...  For example, I have a very complicated DB, but it only updates once a day, so at night I build a aggregation table that de-normalizes all the data to make queries faster and easier. We also have a master DB, that edits are done during the day, but not published. This is done (publishing) with a nightly cron job (as I deal with millions of rows of data), so I build a table, named `tmp_table` then when its done I overwrite the table from the previous day.

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: This amounts to less downtime, as the table from yesterday exists tell it's renamed with the new data.  And instead of dealing with 25+ related tables, I can use only 2. So if you just want to wipe out the old table with the new one you can do a simple `RENAME old_table TO new_table` type query (sorry that was such a long example)

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix in my case it must be a data transfer, @ Mohammad Zare Moghadam i am using laravel 5.

Comment: Personally, I would do it in PURE SQL, handling a large amount of data is NOT what most ORM's do good.  (PS I don't use Laravel)  But I have used Symphony and Doctrine (cringe, I wasn't impressed with Doctrine)...  I gave up on ORM's when they started to bomb out on my millions of row tables.  I had a table that was 170 million rows that I moved to MongoDB (not impressed with it's poor counting abilities) etc...  Big data woes.

Comment: Can you write output of `var_dump($pdr)` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $pn is array Panier::find($pn) returns collection not entity so you should iterate it

```
Panier::find($pn)->each(function($pdr){
    $user = Commande::create([
        'ID_User'    => $pdr->ID_User,
        'ID_Piece'   => $pdr->ID_Piece,
        'QTE'        => $pdr->QTE,
        ]);
   if($user){
        if($pdr->delete())
            {
                echo 'Commande Confirmée';
            }        
        }
});
```

Comment: Replace "each" function to "map" and return delete out in callback. Then you will get collection of delete out

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `findOrFail` and handling `Exception`:

```
function Commande(Request $request) {
    $pn = (int) $request->input('id');
    try {
        $pdr = Panier::findOrFail($pn);
        $pdr->each(function ($item, $key) {
            $user = Commande::create([
                'ID_User'    => $item->ID_User,
                'ID_Piece'   => $item->ID_Piece,
                'QTE'        => $item->QTE,
            ]);
            if ($user && $item->delete()) {
                echo 'Commande Confirmée';
            } 
        });
    } catch (Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        //@Todo handle error
    }
}
```

According to laravel 5.0 documents:

> Retrieving A Model By Primary Key Or Throw An Exception
>
> Sometimes you may wish to throw an exception if a model is not found. To do this, you may use the firstOrFail method:

[Collection](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_each)

Comment: Thanks, but it just a simple transfer, if data is not on the first table then it will not be in the second table, is  there a point of Throwing An Exception in this case?

Comment: I want to sure that `$pdr` is an object of desired type. can you write output of `var_dump($pdr)` here?

Comment: object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#233 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(App\Panier)#236 (26) { ["fillable":protected]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(2) "id" [1]=> string(8) "ID_Ligne" [2]=> string(8) "ID_Piece" [3]=> string(7) "ID_User" [4]=> string(5) "Piece" [5]=> string(3) "QTE" } ...

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing :

`$pdr = Panier::find($pn);`

If the record does not exist, it will return `null`. Then if you do `$pdr->ID_User` it is going to throw an error. Please check beloew updates :

```
<?php 

function Commande(Request $request) {

    $pn = $request->input('id'); 

    $pdr = Panier::find($pn);
    // Model not found
    if(!$pdr){
        return response()->json(['msg' => 'No records found']);

    }
    // Create new Commande
    $user = Commande::create([
        'ID_User'    => $pdr->ID_User ?? 'default_value_for_ID_User',
        'ID_Piece'   => $pdr->ID_Piece ?? 'default_value_for_ID_Piece',
        'QTE'        => $pdr->QTE ?? 'default_value_for_QTE'
    ]);
    // If user is created
    if($user){

        // Delete Panier
        $pdr->delete();
        return response()->json(['msg' => 'Success']);
    }

    return response()->json(['msg' => 'Could not create new Commande']);
}
```

For above to work you need to have :

1. Columns `ID_User`, `ID_Piece` and `QTE` marked as `$fillable = []` in `Commande` Model.
2. You need to have a basic primary key for `Panier` Model, otherwise `delete()` will not work.